# Mindstorms start block is missing

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming

the start block is missing on my mindstorms NXT 2.0 programming space. i cannot run any program without it.

i have tried, restarting the programming window, placing a block and even just undoing to the point that it dissappeared.

So far nothing has worked

Comment: It's buggy software. What OS are you using? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: maybe if you contact LEGO they'll send a replacement

Comment: to be clear, you're speaking on the software platform on your computer, right? not the brick itself?

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the software and installing the latest version (if you weren't installed it)

Answer (score 2):

First try to reinstall NXT 2.0. This should help you.

What's your OS ? Can you give screenshot ?